# Query regarding RF trace width maintenance in a PCB Layout

Tags: rf, pcb-design

I have a query reg. RF PCB design

[image: RF circuit]

This image is the "output end of a power amplifier(PA)", which gives 1.5-j1.7Ohm impedance at output pads(12th & 10th) of the PA. And then it is being matched to 50 Ohm single ended impedance using matching circuitry.

From the following link I have understood that "we no need to worry about controlled impedance when trace length is less than 1.6 cm in my RF PCB design."
                  [Should we maintain the same impedance for the traces carrying RF signal line?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/322750/should-we-maintain-the-same-impedance-for-the-traces-carrying-rf-signal-line)

Note: we have replaced strip-lines in the schematic with inductors.

Questions:
1. Do I need to worry about impedance matching in this design since there is already matching circuitry for achieving 50 Ohm at the end?

2. Is it OK if I start drawing the trace of 50 Ohm impedance from the output pads of the PA though at that points the actual impedance is 1.5-j1.7 Ohms?
3. From where to where I have to consider as total trace length whether from output pads(12th & 10th) of the power amplifier to open end(RF OUT - the end point where the antenna is connected) or length of each Trace segment between the pad to pad(or component to component)?

Comment: You should post the full app note and not just a screenshot. As for how long a trace is before you "need" 50 ohms.....that depends on your system frequency. However, if you can get 50 ohms, you should. What you are trying to design above is a transition from the low impedance of an amplifier to the 50 ohms of an output RF port or antenna.

Comment: In my PCB layout I have maintained same trace width 9.2mils(which can achieve 50 Ohm impedance on 4 Layer stack-up) from RF IN to RF OUT. Is it correct way to maintain impedance control?